# Sandbox/JRE limitations of CloudBees?

Tags: sandbox, java, cloudbees, paas

I'm going to start developing a Java web app that I *believe* I will be deploying to CloudBees, but am concerned about what JRE/sandbox restrictions may apply.

For instance, with Google App Engine, you're not allowed to execute any methods packaged inside `java.io.file` or `java.net`. You're not allowed to start threads without using their custom `ThreadFactory`. You're not allowed to use JNDI, JMX or make calls to remote RDBMSes hosted on 3rd party machines. You're not allowed to use reflection. With GAE, there's *a lot* you're not allowed to do.

Do these same restrictions hold true for CloudBees? I'm guessing *no*, as I just read their entire [developer docs](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Main/) and didn't run across anything of the sort.

**However**, what happens if my app tries to write to the local file system when deployed to their servers? They *must* have *certain* restrictions as to what can run on their machines, if for no other reason than security!

So I ask: what are these restrictions, or where can I find them listed in their docs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: CloudBees Tomcat instances don't support META-INF/context.xml. Instead, if you want to define JNDI objects/lookups for your app, you need to use their command-line tool as explained [here](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DatabaseGuide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I checked (a) there is no sandbox; (b) you can write to the local filesystem, but any files you write there may be discarded if the application is reprovisioned for any reason, i.e. use it for temporary files only. (An optional permanent file store service has been considered as a feature useful for certain applications.)

Comment: Thanks @Jesse Glick (+1) - do you know if this is documented anywhere?